# How can we show this UI in our application

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

How can we show this dialler in our application to initiate a call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder what so tough in this if i have to make a customized look of this..

A TabActivity with its TabHost above the frame content .

Edit Text with Background. cut the image and place it as a backgound of EditText . Change the Font of Text as you want

Cut each and every image make a griview of button or design in any way place images. control their click.

Append EditText content. On Dialer Button initiate call

```
   startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + myEditText.getText())));
```

add permission

```
 < uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.CALL_PHONE”/>
```

Comment: I am a beginner in android application layout design. can u pls give me the sample code of layout design of the above given image

Comment: Do you have to use it to make a phone call or do you need the layout only for some other thing?

Comment: Firstly follow http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html each and every layout example carefully. 

before proceeding to anything else.I am 100% sure you will get the key of answer by your self then..
and if the answer helps you out then dont forget to accept the answer . others will also get the right refernce

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("tel:"
                        + "269-972-8451")));
just try executing  this

Comment: @ Javanator initiating call is working.. creating dialler is the problem

Comment: yes design the layout dear its very easy infact.. go for the tutorials above mentioned..

Answer (score 3):

you can use default Intent as i Shown Below,

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("tel:"
                        + "269-972-8451")));
```

and then Donot forgot to add the following permission in android manifeast file.

```
< uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.CALL_PHONE”/>
```

Comment: @jennifer: if you need to initiate a phone call, then you can use default intent as i shown in my answer and revert back to me, if you had any probs on this

Comment: Thanks  Sankar Ganesh for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can browse the actual Android layout code used by Google on Google Code.
The tabbed layout is in [dialer_activity.xml](http://bit.ly/i5uCrB) the actual dialer layout is in [dialpad.xml](http://bit.ly/fZqpDU)

Comment: Can u pls tell me where i can find out the images that specified in the dialler

Comment: @jennifer The images are part of the Android [source code](http://bit.ly/i0pdq4), but I'm not sure about the licensing. You may want to create your own or find some other buttons out there.